# How to tun a single test with unittest with relative paths?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following project structure:

```
main.py
mainpackage/
   |---tests__/
         |---test_module1.py
   |---package1/
         |--- module1.py
   |---paackage2/
         |--- module2.py
```

my `test_module1.py` looks like  this:

```
import unittest
from ..package1.module1 import toTest
class MyTest(unittest.Testcase):
    def test_mytest(self):
        fu = toTest()
        self.assertEqual(fu,2)

 #more tests omitted

if __name__ == "__main__"
    unittest.main()
```

But when I run this inside `tests`

`python test_module1.py` I obviously get the following error:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

But when I move to the folder `mainpackage/` and run this:

`python -m unittest discover -t .. -v mainpackage.tests.test_module`

it runs all tests in that file. However I can not just pick one test of that file. I tried this:

`python -m unittest discover -t .. -v mainpackage.tests.test_module.MyTest.test_mytest`

Which gave me the following error:

```
ImportError: Start directory is not importable:
```